# AXIsProcessTrusted returns false

Tags: macos, cocoa

What are the reasons why `AXIsProcessTrusted()` might return `false`?

"Enable access for assistive devices" is enabled and `AXAPIEnabled()` returns `true`.

P.S. I have a window-less status bar app if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will return false if your process hasn't been made trusted.

[This mailing list post from 2009](http://lists.apple.com/archives/accessibility-dev/2009/Apr/msg00006.html) explains what `AXMakeProcessTrusted` does. If your app hasn't had that done to it one way or another, then it isn't trusted.

Note that this doesn't mean you can't use Accessibility goodness; [what being trusted means is that you're exempt from the usual restriction that Accessibility must be turned on in System Preferences](http://lists.apple.com/archives/carbon-dev/2010/Feb/msg00043.html). If it is turned on, you can use Accessibility without being trusted; conversely, if you're trusted, you can use Accessibility even if it isn't turned on.

Comment: If I understand you correctly I either need AXAPIEnabled() to return true or AXIsProcessTrusted to return true?